# Can a mapping from real line to $(0,1]$ be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a mapping from real line to $(0,1]$ be continuous? Also is it bijective? Please give me proof.
I checked that between the same intervals; there will be a homeomorphic mapping but here I guess a mapping can be bijective but not continuous. I was trying to get some examples and i couldn't find one.

Comment: Please show some effort at homework. The answers are yes and maybe.

Comment: Instead of asking for a proof can you give an argument for why it probably isn't true and ask of *help* in how to think about a proof of the necessary points....  I doubt anyone is going to be inclined to just *hand* you a proof.

Comment: There's one very obvious difficult aspect of trying to find a continuous function from $\mathbb R \to (0,1]$.  Does one thing jump out at you and pound you over the head?  There should be one that just screams at you.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I have edited it.

Comment: And just because I'm confused at a very small question, you can't talk to me like that. There may be reasons behind that. You could say what you've said nicely. Otherwise Don't just answer.

Comment: Thanks @copper hat I've edited my question. Please provide some help if you could.

Comment: The function $f(x) =  {1 \over 1+x^2}$ is a continuous function that maps the real line onto $(0,1]$ but is not bijective.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is continuous and bijective, Then there must be some $x^*$ such that $f(x^*) = 1$. What can you say about $f$ on $x< x^*$ and $x>x^*$ that must lead to a contradiction? For example, you must have $f(x^*-1) < f(x^*)$ and similarly for $x^*+1$. Something about this little triangle gives a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! That way $f(x)$ will be greater than 1 and which will be a contradiction as the co domain is the closed interval which can not go beyond 1. Am I right?

Comment: No. You will have $f(x^*-1) < f(x^*)$ and $f(x^*) > f(x^*+1)$ and so there is some $y$ between $f(x^*) $ and $\max (f(x^*-1),f(x^*+1))$ such that there is some $x_1< x^*$ and some $x_2> x^*$ with $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

Comment: Sigh. Our collective annoyance doesn't arise from it being a small problem -- we've helped tons of people with those. The annoyance stems from your showing small *effort*. Telling us how we ought to behave while doing you a favor ... well, that's just icing on the cake.

Comment: The OP needs to do a little more work here, but it never helps to tell someone who is trying to solve a problem that something is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be continuous; e.g., consider the gaussian

$y(x) = \exp \left (-\dfrac{x^2}{\Sigma^2} \right ), 0 \ne \Sigma \in \Bbb R ; \tag 1$

note that

$y(0) = \exp(0) = 1, \tag 2$

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; 0 < y(x) \le 1, \tag 3$

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; y(x) = y(-x), \tag 4$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} y(x) = 0; \tag 5$

it then follows from the intermediate value theorem that for any

$c \in (0, 1], \; \exists x_c \in \Bbb R, \; y(\pm x_c) = c; \tag 6$

I leave fleshing out the details of this assertion to my vast readership.  This establishes the existence of a continuous (analytic, even) $f: \Bbb R \to (0, 1]$.

I doubt there are any *bijective, continuous* such functions; perhaps I shall return with a proof of same.

Comment: +1 from part of your vastness.

Comment: @copper.hat: vast thanks my friend.  Cheers!